# Search Result from another wordpress website

Tags: search

I am wondering, is it possible to get the search result from Website A and display it to Website B, assuming that both websites are not part of multisite?

Comment: Do you have admin access to both website?

Comment: Yes, I have access on the two websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will be possible.

I would suggest integrating your WordPress websites search with Google search and then you can specify the site/s (in your cause Site B) you wish to search when a users performs a search on your current site (Site A)

Here is a awesome and simple tutorial a-z tutorial on how to set it all up: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-google-search-in-a-wordpress-site/

Goodluck :-)

Comment: if I add google search, would it be easier if I just change the action value in the search form to the url of website B as if I am searching through website B itself?

Comment: If you add Google Search you will be bypassing the default WordPress search entirely so no that wont work.

Answer (score 2):

When you have access to both site. You can create an data feed url which will return `JSON` data.

### Plugin That Provides Data Feed (install on Site A)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE Search Data Feed
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com
Description: Provides interface to search and get result in JSON data
Author: Sisir
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://developerpage.net
*/

    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse144893_search', 'wpse144893_search_data'); // allow logged out users
    add_action('wp_ajax_wpse144893_search', 'wpse144893_search_data'); // allow logged in users

    function wpse144893_search_data(){

        $errors = array();
        $data = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => '',
            'result' => array()
        );

        if(!isset($_REQUEST['term']) || empty($_REQUEST['term']))
            $errors[] = 'No search term given!';


        if(!isset($_REQUEST['limit']) || empty($_REQUEST['limit']))
            $limit = 10;
        else
            $limit = (int) $_REQUEST['limit'];

        if(empty($errors)){

            $term = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['term']);

            // setup query data
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => $limit,
                's' => $term
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args); // run query

            $results = array();
            if($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
                $post_item = array(
                    'title' => get_the_title(),
                    'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
                    'permalink' => get_permalink()
                );
                $results[] = $post_item;
            endwhile;
                $data['status'] = 'success';
                $data['message'] = 'Results found!';
                $data['result'] = $results;
            else:
                $errors[] = 'No post found!';
                $data['message'] = $errors;
            endif;
        }

        echo json_encode($data); // print json

        die(); // kill the script
    }
```

[Link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/prionkor/d1c978e0bd0edbee3a67)

### Returned Result Would be something like This:

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "message":"Results found!",
   "result":[
        {
            "title":"Deadly car bomb blasts hit Shia areas in Baghdad",
            "excerpt":"Several car bombs have exploded across the Iraqi capital Baghdad, killing at least 20 people and injuring scores more, officials say. The attacks are reported to have targeted mainly Shia areas in the city. Security sources told the BBC three explosions rocked the neighbourhoods of Ourfally, Kiyara and Falah Street in the eastern suburb of […]",
            "permalink":"http:\/\/localhost\/l\/blog\/deadly-car-bomb-blasts-hit-shia-areas-in-baghdad\/"}
            ]
    }
```

### Explanation

We create a data feed using ajax api. There is not need to call the `admin-ajax.php` file using ajax. We can use simple HTTP_API for that or CURL. Our url endpoint for getting search results is `http://<your_domain.com>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpse144893_search`

As you can see from the validation code. You pass the search term as `term` key. You can also pass `limit` which is not required and default is `10`. Here is how a search term will look like.

```
http://<your_domain.com>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpse144893_search&term=<my_search>&limit=50
```

You can just paste the url on browser to see the result.This is a basic plugin to give you an idea.

### Possible Improvements For The Plugin

1. Custom/Pretty url endpoint via rewrite api.
2. Securing the endpoint via secret key.
3. Support for XML. I am more comfortable with `JSON` but you can return `XML` if you are comfortable with it.

### How to Call From Site B

Well as you can see the url is pretty straightforward. So, you can use `HTTP_API` or php curl to get the result. Below is an example how it can be done using [`HTTP_API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)

```
$url = 'http://<your_domain.com>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
$args = array(
    'action' => 'wpse144893_search',
    'term' => 'My Search Term',
    'limit' => 50
);

$url = add_query_arg($args, $url);

$response = wp_remote_get($url);

if(!is_wp_error($response)){
    // additional checks can be done here for correct http code.
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response); // retrieve the response body

    $result = json_decode($result); // now we get the result object :)
}else{
    // handle error
}
```

Now you can process `$result` object to get search result.

Comment: does this plugin affect all search fields in the site as the client is planning on having 2 search fields with different site to search for?

Comment: No, it doesn't interacts with WP default search. It does different query with AJAX API. You can improve the plugin to add more query fields and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will load the search results for *JavaScript* from my website

```
$response = wp_remote_get( "http://ahrengot.com/?s=javascript" );
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
echo $body;
```

This returns the HTML as a string which you can RegEx or search/replace your way through, if you want to isolate the search results. However, I would recommend doing this with jQuery instead, for 2 reasons:

1. The example above will very likely slow down your page load speed, as it has to *fully load the other page* before it can send back the HTML to the client. Loading with AJAX will display you page instantly and then load the results second. That is a much nicer user experience.
2. jQuery will handle the string parsing for you too.

Here's the same example with jQuery

```
$("#you-container-element").load( "http://ahrengot.com/?s=javascript #container-element" );
```

`#container-element` is the element on ahrengot.com/the remote page that contains the search results.